# Does Android studio includes build machine info into apk?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-security

I'm wondering, does Google track developers by some fingerprint of their development environment? Is any personal info included in app, or during reports in Android studio?
Is it legal if so?

Comment: "Is it legal if so?" don't ask legal questions on SO, your question will be closed as off-topic, as we aren't experts of the law here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any of our release APKs can be built by any of our developers, on any machine, so there wouldn't any unique machine fingerprint. The only fingerprint that Google cares about is the signing cert's fingerprint, and it can't be changed.